# Datetime with miliseconds from pandas dataframe to mysql db

Tags: mysql, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe looks like this:

```
opentrap  limitswitchclose  limitswitchopen  traploop  photocells              datetime                                                                                                    
1                 1                0         0           0         2018-08-26 08:05:33.365
1                 1                0         0           0         2018-08-26 08:05:38.603
1                 0                0         0           0         2018-08-26 08:05:40.616
1                 0                0         0           0         2018-08-26 08:05:41.821
1                 0                0         0           0         2018-08-26 08:05:44.234
```

but when i run this code:

```
df.to_sql(name='database', chunksize=20000, con=conn, index=True, if_exists='replace')
```

it looks like this in mysql:

[MYSQL Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soOAg.png)
i found out that you to change the DATETIME to DATETIME(3) which would display milliseconds, but they are just rounded to 0 in that case. when I applied to my code nothing changed in my sql

```
df.to_sql(name='database', chunksize=20000, con=conn, index=True, dtype={"datetime": DATETIME(3)}, if_exists='replace')
```

So how do i get mysql to display my date time exactly like in my dataframe?

Comment: this is certainly not a solution, but a work around. Can you store the date into different columns? that way you can break out the time even further into columns. Could also help when you only need to look at hourly,minute, second level data

Comment: I don't know how i didnt find that thread. But yes it is duplicate and the problem was      fsp=3 instead of just 3